# Custom UITableViewCell with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

Cell doesn't receive touch events, when there is UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell. Is there any way to cancel tap events for UIScrollView (needs only to handle scrolling)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need touches to go through, implement a subclass of UIScrollView, and add these:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    // Pass to parent
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Pass to parent
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The cell only interecepts taps, so it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This is brilliant! I was pulling my hair on this one.