# UITableView didSelectRow executed on wrong Cell even though touchesCancelled called of custom UITableViewCell containing custom UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm currently trying to write a music player application for iPhone. Part of the design is the possibility to swipe across single entries of the song list to reveal additional options (like in the iOS 7 Mail.app).

I realized this with the help of a custom UITableViewCell, which contains a custom UIScrollView and two UIViews (one for the actual content and one for the "background-menu"), which works mostly as expected. As the UIScrollView seemed to take all the touches on TableViewCells, which disabled the option to actually play a song, I forwarded the touch events (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851323/custom-uitableviewcell-with-uiscrollview) for example):

CellScrollView.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (![self isDragging]){
        [[self superview] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (![self isDragging]){
        [[self superview] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (![self isDragging]){
        [[self superview] touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesCancelled: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event{
    if (![self isDragging]){
        [[self superview] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Now my problem is the following:
When I press and hold on a cell in the list and start to scroll then the mediaplayer doesn't start to play (as expected). But when I then tap on any other entry of the list, not the title I tapped on gets played but the one I first hold down and then started scrolling. This only happens if I don't scroll and stop the scrolling by tapping anymore after the tap-and-hold (which brings up an "Unexpected touch phase during scrolling" in the log, I guess this is what finally cancels the tap-and-hold).

Is there any way to correct this behavior (everything works fine if I just use a normal UITableViewCell so I guess the UIScrollView breaks everything)?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you.

What I did to fix it is to set the view controller containing the tableview as a delegate of the cell.

Then I set a delegate selector on my cell to pass the tap gestures to the view controller containing my tableview.

@class GameSequenceCell;

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didSelectCell:(CustomCell *)sender;
@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
/*
 * Some stuffs
 */
@end
```

Then I've added a UITapGestureRecognizer on the cell directly. This must be done at the initialisation of the cell.

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) [self prepareForFirstUse];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) [self prepareForFirstUse];
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareForFirstUse
{
    /*
     * The tap gesture recognizer is needed to be able to tap on the scroll view in the cell
     * Calling the singleTapGestureCaptured will trigger the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
     * of the EventPanelVC tableview delegate.
     */
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}
```

I then have implemented in the cell:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    [self.delegate didSelectCell:self];
}
```

The delegate being the view controller containing the tableview in which the cell is.

Now all the tap gesture in the cell are catched and in the view controller I implement:

```
- (void)didSelectCell:(CustomCell *)sender;
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfTouchedCell = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:sender.object];
    if(indexPathOfTouchedCell)
    {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfTouchedCell animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfTouchedCell];
    }
}
```

This is how I fixed this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. In the mean time, I switched to a UIPanGestureRecognizer to scroll my views "by hand". For the moment, I'm going to stick with this solution, but as using a scrollView seems to be possible now again, I might come back and try it again.